# Making divs stay the same place when resizing window

Tags: html, css

First of all im new programmer, so dont judge quickly :). Anyways ive been struggling with this problem for some time now. The problem is when im resizing(scaling whatever) the window, it messes around with ALL my elements. When resizing my website, you should just see less, than before. Not move around elements.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="leftblock">
   </div>



<div id="rightBlock">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftblock {   

 margin-left: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
 height: 100px;
 width: 3px;  

}



#rightBlock { 
 margin-right: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: right;
 height: 100px;
 width: 3px;


}
```

To be sure what i mean, test the code in an editor, and then try resize the window.

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/fwmfL/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want them to move around, place the elements in a fixed size parent container.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fwmfL/1/)</kbd>

#### CSS

```
#container {
 width: 1000px;
}

#leftblock {   
 margin-left: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: left;
 height: 100px;
 width: 3px;  
}

#rightBlock { 
 margin-right: 20%;
 background-color: red;
 float: right;
 height: 100px;
 width: 3px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftblock">
    </div>

    <div id="rightBlock">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you VEEEERY much :D Just what i looked for. Cant approve answer before 7 min, but i will there! THANKS

Answer (score 2):

it's because you're using percentages for your margins. If you want them to stay in place, used a fixed unit like `px` or `em`. For example

```
margin-right: 100px;
```

Comment: It's also because they are floated, so they will float with respect to their container. As the container shrinks, they will be pushed below each other.

Comment: true. and if you really want them to stay put use `position: absolute`